# Angularjs 4, how can I use ngfor to show 3 consecutive items in the same tag?

Tags: angular

As I mentioned in the question, I have a table and I use ngFor to show all item in the array. For now I am doing it by:

```
<td>
  <div *ngFor="let item in array>
    {{item}}
  </div>
</td>
```

However, I want three consecutive items in the same div (or the same line, and the next three on the next line). How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want the 3 consecutive items in same div one below the other or in same line ??

Comment: In the same line

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I would group them in the component:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let group of grouped">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let el of group">
          {{ el }}
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  `,
  selector: 'test'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  public grouped: number[][] = [];

  // Don't make it zero
  private numPerGroup = 3;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let testArray: number[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let group: number[];

    for (let i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
      if (!(i % this.numPerGroup)) {
        this.grouped.push(group = []);
      }

      group.push(testArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but this won't print in the same line as user is requesting @Frank Modica

Comment: @praveen What do you mean? It prints `<div>0 1 2</div> <div>3 4 5</div>` etc. So it's 3 per `div`, and each element in the `div` is on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Stole the answer from this question: [Angular 5 display *ngfor horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519400/angular-5-display-ngfor-horizontally)

Use the Angular Flex-Layout package and you can add this as the template to Frank Modica's answer and it should work:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of grouped">
    <div fxLayout="row">
        <div *ngFor="let el of group"> {{el}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is with a css grid

component:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div *ngFor="let item of array">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyskpw