# Angular 5 display *ngfor horizontally

Tags: angular, css, ngfor, angular5

i'm building my first angular app using latest version and i need some help to display some informations in a specific position.

**app.component.ts:**

```
socials = [
  {
    name: 'Github',
    icon: 'fa fa-github fa-2x',
    link: 'https://www.github.com/..';
  },
  {
    name: 'Twitter',
    icon: 'fa fa-twitter fa-2x',
    link: 'https://www.twitter.com/..';
  },
  {
    name: 'Keybase',
    icon: '',
    link: 'https://keybase.io/..';
  },
...
..
.
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 links" *ngFor="let social of socials">
      <a href={{social.link}} target="_blank">
        <i class={{social.icon}} aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span>{{social.name}}</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so this display it like this: 
[vertically :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GpKr.png)

but me i want to display it horizontally like this: [horizontally :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ5mv.png)

so how can i do that while using *ngfor to load those informations ?
if i cant , what do you advice me?

Comment: try to change `class="col-sm-12 links"` to `class="col-sm-2 links"`.

Comment: I assume that it's associate with bootstrap styles. Try to add flex with row direction for your `links` class. In your css, add: `.links { display: flex; flex-direction: row }`. If it works and you want to have some fun with flex, check https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the package Angular Flex Layout. You just have to use the `row` layout.

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div *ngFor...></div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the [@angular/flex-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout) library.

And  a [demo here](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs)

Comment: ah thank you very much, i used ```<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">```

Answer (score 2):

### app.component.html:

```
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 links" *ngFor="let social of socials">
    <div style="float:left;height:50px;"  [ngStyle]="{'width': 'calc(100% /' + socials.length + ')'}">
          <a href={{social.link}} target="_blank">
            <i class={{social.icon}} aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span>{{social.name}}</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zd69fh?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: why a float? Use display:inline-block

Comment: it worked too but <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center"> like J-R Choiniere told is more simple and easy, but thank you too

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you still need this, but just **wrap your ngFor in a row div**.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemList">
    <span class="ml-2 badge badge-pill badge-primary"> {{item?.name}} </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's an example of what that might look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RBCi.png)