# Styling dom elements generated by ngfor

Tags: angular, dom, styling, ngfor

**Background:** So im gettting some data from the back end that I'm storing as an Array on my Angular front end. Now Im trying to display each of these elements (which are products) on the template. What I'm basically trying to achieve is products on a page that users can browse.

**Problem:** The problem is that ngfor is simply drawing the elements one after the other in a vertical line on the template. What I want is to be able to apply general style settings(perhaps on the parent element hosting ngfor?) so the elements go from the top left of the page to the top right in a line from 1 to X number of elements according to viewport width, and then continue as such on the following rows untill there are none left in the original array. PS. I have tried using css grid and flexbox in the parent element but they simply get ignored by the template.

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the direction from where I could achieve the desired outcome.

My Template code is as follows:

```
<div id="backGroundImage">
  <div id="salesPageContainer">
    <div id="saleItemsContainer" >
      <div *ngFor="let saleItem of saleItems" id="itemContainer" >
        <p id="itemName">{{ saleItem.itemName }}</p>
        <p id="itemPrice">{{ saleItem.itemPrice }}</p>
        <img [src]="imageUrl + saleItem.imageID" alt="" id="itemImage" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Check Duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519400/angular-5-display-ngfor-horizontally)

Comment: There are no special rules concerning styling elements generated by *ngFor. Just put a class on the element and style that class in the css. BTW, now you're generating X elements with the same `id` attribute, this isn't good HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check sample implementation here** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-horizontal-ngfor)

If you have **bootstrap** in your app add `class="d-flex flex-wrap" like below`

```
<div id="backGroundImage">
  <div id="salesPageContainer">
    <div id="saleItemsContainer" class="d-flex flex-wrap">
      <div *ngFor="let saleItem of saleItems" id="itemContainer" >
        <p id="itemName">{{ saleItem.itemName }}</p>
        <p id="itemPrice">{{ saleItem.itemPrice }}</p>
        <img [src]="imageUrl + saleItem.imageID" alt="" id="itemImage" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In **plain css** apply css `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` to `id="saleItemsContainer"`

```
<div id="backGroundImage">
  <div id="salesPageContainer">
    <div id="saleItemsContainer">
      <div *ngFor="let saleItem of saleItems" id="itemContainer" >
        <p id="itemName">{{ saleItem.itemName }}</p>
        <p id="itemPrice">{{ saleItem.itemPrice }}</p>
        <img [src]="imageUrl + saleItem.imageID" alt="" id="itemImage" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using CSS Grid**

```
<div id="backGroundImage">
  <div id="salesPageContainer">
    <div id="saleItemsContainer">
      <div *ngFor="let saleItem of saleItems" id="itemContainer" >
        <p id="itemName">{{ saleItem.itemName }}</p>
        <p id="itemPrice">{{ saleItem.itemPrice }}</p>
        <img [src]="imageUrl + saleItem.imageID" alt="" id="itemImage" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add css to `saleItemsContainer`

```
#saleItemsContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-row-gap: 0.4rem;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your response. It is very helpful. I was wondering if there is a way to make css grid work as well. 
For example lets say I add     **display: grid;**  to     id="saleItemsContainer". What should i add to id="itemContainer" so that a general style is applied to all the elements of the array drawn on the template?

Comment: @BlitzMee check the stackblitz i have updated with Css grid example if you find it useful kindly accept the answer and upvote

Comment: This works perfectly. Thankyou so much.
I've accepted the answer. I can't upvote though as i got a couple of downvotes on my question and my rep is no longer high enough to do so.

Comment: I now have 16 rep for accepting the answer though. Upvoted as deserved :)